# What are the security risks of letting the users upload content to my site?

Tags: web-application, appsec, file-upload

As a web designer (not a security expert) I wonder: If I allow users to upload content to my website (videos, images and text files), what are the real risks involved?

Comment: See also additional questions (but not quite duplicate): http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/323/which-files-are-more-insecure-than-others and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/235/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's a couple of risks from allowing content to be uploaded onto your site, but how important they are to you will likely depend on exactly how the site you're designing will work.

First up is malware upload.  If an attacker can upload malware onto your site and that malware is downloaded and executed by your users then that's likely to be a problem.  Preventing this usually relies on a combination of restricting the types of file that can be uploaded (one point to note is that you shouldn't just rely on file extension here), and using malware scanning on uploaded content. Of course the scanning side of things will only stop known signatures, and can be bypassed fairly easily.

Second potential problem is if they can upload active content and have that executed by your application.  So for example if your site uses php, then if they can upload a php script and then get it to run as part of your application then they are likely to be able to take control of the server, or at least access other information that exists in the app.

One approach I've seen to addressing this is to ensure that the uploaded files are not placed in the web root and ensuring that the web server will not execute files from that location.

A third risk, is users uploaded "illegal" material. This can be a tricky legal question to sort, but if you allow user generated content you're likely to have to deal with it sooner or later.  The fix for this seems to be primarily procedural.  Have a good relationship with your hosting company and ISP and ensure that you can respond to requests to have content removed quickly, if you're hosting in a jurisdiction that requires content to be taken down if a request comes in (eg, a DMCA request).

Comment: Also, potential of flooding your server, thus causing DoS.

Comment: A fourth risk, severe yet easy to miss: Upload of _client-side active content_, such as JavaScript (including HTML/CSS with embedded JavaScript), Java applets, Flash objects, etc., all of which can be used to perform cookie-stealing attacks and work around same-origin policies. [Your website might think the user uploaded a GIF image, when it's really a Java JAR.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gifar) _Always_ host user uploads on a separate domain, cf. googleusercontent.com, upload.wikimedia.org, etc.

Answer (score 9):

If your server is not well configured, it could lead to execution of malicious code in the context of your server and take control over your files. One example of that is well known PHP backdoor *c99shell*. There are few recommendations to make this feature more secure:

1. Use some other domain (or subdomain) to store files uploaded by users
2. Make sure, users cannot upload any type of file the server will execute (check the content type or use language specific tools to read the content of file and check the right mime type)
3. Make sure uploaded files have not permissions to be executed.
4. When allowing other users to download the file, it is sometimes useful to force it as attachment using the Content-Disposition HTTP header

Comment: How can we ge the right mime type?

Comment: Depends on programming language - for example in Java, you can use [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/)

Comment: PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: Python: https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic

Answer (score 1):

FileInclude is one of the worst security holes in websites, just think what will happen if some one uplode C99 Shell (which is one of the worst php scripts I've ever seen) to your site and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

An attacker can upload malicious codes that can break the authentication or upload an .exe file. Such files when opened by the other user can cause major security problems and cause the system performance.

Answer (score 0):

From security stand point of view - allowing user to upload any kind of executable without proper screening is a big risk.Rule of thumb will be -

- Don't place user uploaded content in user accessible location on Web directory.
- Don't allow user to upload server configuration files. (In some case user will restrict uploading php files but still allows .htaccess to be uploaded :) )

I have seen some site trying to disallow PHP script upload while happily allowing SSI to be uploaded and executed.